# Why I cannot find (using which) usermod as a regular user in RHEL7

Tags: permissions, rhel, which

Any ideas why the `which` command is unable to find the `usermod` command in rhel 7. Here is what I did (and corresponding output)

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-4-109 ~]$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-4-109 ~]$ which usermod
/usr/bin/which: no usermod in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin)
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-4-109 ~]$ sudo su
[root@ip-10-0-4-109 ec2-user]# which usermod
/sbin/usermod
[root@ip-10-0-4-109 ec2-user]# readlink -f /sbin/
/usr/sbin
```

So the gist of the issue is that `usermod` is physically located in `/usr/sbin/usermod`. This directory `/usr/sbin` is in `ec2-user` search path. But for some reason `which` command is not returning it when I run it as `ec2-user`.

Any ideas why this is happening on RHEL 7? I also have Ubuntu 14.04 and it works as expected (both root and regular user can see `usermod` in `/usr/sbin`).

After initial post here is what else I found out:
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

I found some addition information and I think this may have something to do with this:

On RHEL 7 the permission bits for `usermod`

```
-rwxr-x---. 1 root root 113800 Jun 28  2016 /usr/sbin/usermod
```

On Ubuntu 14.04 the permission bits for `usermod`

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 110296 May 16 19:37 /usr/sbin/usermod
```

So I am guessing not having read permission for regular user on `usermod` maybe causing this?

Comment: Read and execute, yep!

Comment: If it's a binary executable and not an interpreted script, you only need the e`x`ecute permission to run it

Answer (score 0):

`usermod` is a program that runs only from root.
To find out locations:

```
sudo which usermod
/usr/sbin/usermod
```